# Insert React Component or Element into specific div which is not DOM Element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, react-bootstrap

Need help!

I try to insert one React Component into specific div generated by another component, more precisely, by google.maps.Map()
See details here:

```
class GoogleMap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loc: {
        lat: 46.31555,
        lng: 44.25878
      },
      zoom: 18,
      buttonAddNewStoreClicked: false
    };
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
      return false;
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    // get access to GoogleMap
    var gmap = this; 

    // render googlemap
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
      center: { lat: this.state.loc.lat, lng: this.state.loc.lng },
      zoom: this.state.zoom,
      zoomControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      fullscreenControl: false
    });

    // create custom control - button
    var buttonAddNewStoreDiv = document.createElement('div');
    // const buttonAddNewStoreDiv = React.createElement('div', {id: 'button-add-new-store'}, 'BUTTON');

    buttonAddNewStoreDiv.id = 'button-add-new-store';
    buttonAddNewStoreDiv.index = 1;

    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(buttonAddNewStoreDiv);



    // add click event listener to the map
    this.map.addListener('click', function(e) {
      console.log(document.querySelector('#button-add-new-store'));
      console.log(gmap);
      if (gmap.state.buttonAddNewStoreClicked) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: e.latLng,
          map: this
        });
      }

      gmap.setState({ buttonAddNewStoreClicked: false });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div id="map" ref="map">
      </div>
    ); 
  }
}

export default GoogleMap;
```

this is my App.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';
import StoreContainer from './components/StoreContainer'
import GoogleMap from './components/GoogleMap'
import NavBarHeader from './components/NavBarHeader'
// import AddNewStoreModalDialog from './components/AddNewStoreModalDialog'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="App">
        <div class="header">
          <NavBarHeader />
        </div>
        <div class="main-container">
          <div class="left-container">
            <GoogleMap />
          </div>
          <div class="right-container">
            <StoreContainer />
          </div>
        </div>   
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

that generates following html code:

```
<div id="root">
  <div class="App">
    <div class="header">...</div>
    <div class="main-container">
      <div class="left-container">
        <div id="map" style="...">
          <div style="..">
            <div class="gm-style" style="..">
              <div>...</div>
              <div>...</div>
              ...
              ...
              <div id="button-add-new-store" style="z-index=0; position: absolute; ... "></div>
              ...
              ...
              <div>...</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-container">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

is it possible to insert the following react component AddNewStoreModalDialog into the div with id="button-add-new-store"? If so, how to do that?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class AddNewStoreModalDialog extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: true
    };
    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
  }

  open() {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  }

  close() {
    alert('close')
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="add-new-store-button">
        <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.open}>
          + New store
        </Button>
        <Modal id="add-new-store-modal" show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>

          <Modal.Body>
            One fine body...
          </Modal.Body>

          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
            <Button bsStyle="primary">Save changes</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>

        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddNewStoreModalDialog;
```

Comment: Why do you need it in that particular `div`?

Comment: Maybe I do not need. But is it possible somehow?

Comment: Why don't you do it thru jsx?

Comment: @eric-guan I believe he wants to render a React component inside of a div generated by google maps. Maybe this would be helpful https://blog.rapid7.com/2016/12/09/how-to-render-components-outside-the-main-react-app/

Comment: In the google api - there should be options/examples that show you how to customize the different sections of code you want to display in addition to colors. You'll have to look to see if that is the same place you want your div.

Comment: I got react way. I don't need to insert my button into the google maps div. I positioned the button absolutely above the map.